# Kotlin. How to use Double.fromBits?

Tags: java, kotlin, double

I have an exponent and a fraction and I want to convert them into Double.

Here is how I am trying to do that

```
private const val FRACTION_BITS_COUNT = 52
private const val EXPONENT_BITS_COUNT = 11

private fun createDoubleFromBits(exponent: Long, fraction: Long): Double {
    var bits = exponent shl FRACTION_BITS_COUNT or if (fraction < 0) -fraction else fraction
    val sign = if (fraction < 0) 1L else 0L
    bits = (sign shl (FRACTION_BITS_COUNT + EXPONENT_BITS_COUNT)) or bits
    return Double.fromBits(bits)
}

val result = createDoubleFromBits(
    exponent = -43,
    fraction = 4343
)
```

While executing this I am getting `result = -2.554675596206905E294`. However I am expecting to get `4343e-43`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure if need to use Double::fromBits? You may simply use something like `fraction * 10.0.pow(exponent)`

Comment: What is wrong? Your assumption about how doubles are represented (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format): the fraction is not some value between 1 and some large integer, it is a fractional value between 1.0 and (almost) 2 where the 1 before the (decimal) point is not stored. And the exponent is not a decimal exponent, it is a (biased) twos exponent where the exponent value 0 is stored as 1023.

Comment: @yahorbarkouski I guess I will not get the same precision using the formula, so the result will be a little bit different and also, I want it to work as fast as possible, so fraction * 10.0.pow(exponent) is not a solution here

Comment: If you're running on the JVM, using Math.scalb in combination with casting is your best option.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing two things.

First, you must add a bias of 1023 to the exponent.

Second, the mantissa is not expressed the way you think of.  If the fraction bits are b1b2b3..., the fraction is 1.b1b2b3... * 2^(exp - 1023) * sign.  You cannot simply put 4343 in and expect it to work.